# AjaxSubmitButton in Yii framework does not save

Tags: php, ajax, yii

after succeeding in not refreshing the page after submission, my ajaxSubmitButton does not save the data. When I click on the button, it removes the content of the input fields but does not  save the data. No message is displayed despite the error and success parameters.

In my form submission,  the code for submit button is the following

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
      'Save',
      Yii::app()->createUrl('post/viewComment'),
      array(
           'success'=>'js:function(data){
                    alert("commentSubmitted");}',
           'error'=>'js:function(data){
                    alert("comment NOT Submitted");}',  
            )
    ); 
 ?>
```

My controller action code is

```
public function actionViewComment()
    {   
        $post=$this->loadModel();
        $comment=$this->newComment($post);

        $this->renderPartial('_viewComment',array(
            'model'=>$post,
            'comment'=>$comment,
        ));
```

the viewCommment view,  display the _view view to list the comments and at the end display the _form view  to make the user input the new comment

the newComment function contains the following

```
protected function newComment($post)
    {
        $comment=new Comment;
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='comment-form')
        {

            echo CActiveForm::validate($comment);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
        if(isset($_POST['Comment']))
        {
            $comment->attributes=$_POST['Comment'];
            if($post->addComment($comment))
            {
                if($comment->status==Comment::STATUS_PENDING)
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('commentSubmitted','Thank you for your comment. Your comment will be posted once it is approved.');
                   $this->refresh();
            }
        }
        return $comment;
    }
```

Actually, I use the blog demo from Yii Framework, I though it was a good starting point to learn Yii Framework.

the home page display   list of posts.   (it renderPartial _view.php.)

I create the ajax button to be able to list the commments associated with a given post and display an input form for new comment at the bottom of the form.

I added a second button with the "classical submit"

```
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Submit' : 'Save'); ?>
```

it works but redirect me to the list of the comments, that's what I wanted to avoid;
By using AjaxsubmitButton.  When I put my cursor over the classical button or the Ajax button, the link is the same ...../blog/index.php/post/viewComment?id=...

The display is the following

post 1

post 2

```
 comment 1

 comment 2

 comment 3
```

---

Add comment

```
Input Field
```

AjaxSubmit Button

---

post 3

and when I click on the ajaxsubmit button, I have the following

post 1

post 2

```
 comment 1

 comment 2

 comment 3
```

---

Add comment

```
Input Field
```

AjaxSubmit Button

---

---

Add comment

```
Input Field
```

AjaxSubmit Button

---

post 3

So I got a second form window below the first one. And the comment is not saved.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: can you add your controller code also?

Comment: I think you are process the $_POST data in your controller. So you have to mention the POST in your ajax options array.

Comment: @kumar_v   I just added the controller code in the question

Comment: @kumar_v  .  Thank you Kumar but it still not works.  I added explanation in my  post.  You'll see that I added a classical button and the save is done.  Bur I want make the ajax button works as explained in the post.

Comment: did you try my solution?

Comment: Yes I tried it. But it does not work.  @kumar_v

Comment: did you check in your ajax call request in browser? in firebug net section

Comment: No but I'm going to use it.  @kumar_v

Comment: I cannot figure out where the problem is.  Actually, when I click on the save button,  it add, below the comment form, another comment form.    Look at the display that I added to the post please.@kumar_v

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46637/discussion-between-sanfisa-and-kumar-v)

Answer (score 0):

You are processing the data from POST. But you didn't mention in code.

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
      'Save',
      Yii::app()->createUrl('post/viewComment'),
      array(
           'type'=>'POST',
           'dataType'=>'json',
           'success'=>'js:function(data){
                    alert("commentSubmitted");}',
           'error'=>'js:function(data){
                    alert("comment NOT Submitted");}',  
            )
    ); 
 ?>
```